# Disable OpenMP for code coverage of an R package on Github actions

Tags: r, github-actions, openmp, r-package, covr

I have an R package with C++ code and I'm using GitHub actions to run unit tests and code coverage with `covr`. Everything is working.

However, code coverage does not work with parallelized blocks of C++ code. Thus, significant portions of the code are nonexistent from the coverage point of view (not missed, not hit, just nonexistent).

Consequently, my plan it to disable OpenMP specifically on Github for the coverage action and compile the code without support of OpenMP. I see 2 options:

- Changing the `Makevars`, removing `$(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)` for this specific action, but I have no idea how to do it.
- Changing a global variable in the `.yaml` file. But again I have no idea what to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a third option. I'm running the coverage on macOS instead of Linux because it has no native support of OpenMP.